# gremlin from titan 1.0.0 is not running out of the box on windows

Tags: titan, gremlin

I'm following the http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/getting-started.html guide on my windows machine.

but i'm getting stuck at the very first step, getting gremlin to run:

```
>bin\gremlin.bat
Error opening zip file or JAR manifest missing : ..\lib\jamm-0.3.0.jar
Error occurred during initialization of VM
agent library failed to init: instrument
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Found a solution [in this google group](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/aureliusgraphs/tZ0XhwJY9jQ/2jkdD7TDAwAJ) for this issue and more:

to run gremlin edit the gremlin.bat file:

Change:

```
set LIBDIR=..\lib
```

To:

```
set LIBDIR=lib
```

Change:

```
if "%CP%" == "" (
set CP=%LIBDIR%\%1
)else (
set CP=%CP%;%LIBDIR%\%1
)
```

To:

```
if "%CP%" == "" (
set CP=%1
)else (
set CP=%CP%;%1
)
```

also, to add command history abilities to the gremlin command line:

in the gremlin.bat file add to the set JAVA_OPTIONS line (solution from same source):

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms32m -Xmx512m -javaagent:%LIBDIR%\jamm-0.3.0.jar
```

add:

```
set JAVA_OPTIONS=-Xms32m -Xmx512m -javaagent:%LIBDIR%\jamm-0.3.0.jar -Djline.terminal=none
```

and lastly, to change the loglevel:
add a file named logback.xml in the titan-1.0.0-hadoop1 folder containing:
[(solution from the same source)](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!msg/aureliusgraphs/tZ0XhwJY9jQ/2jkdD7TDAwAJ)

```
<configuration>
  <appender name="STDOUT" class="ch.qos.logback.core.ConsoleAppender">
    <!-- encoders are assigned the type
         ch.qos.logback.classic.encoder.PatternLayoutEncoder by default -->
    <encoder>
      <pattern>%d{HH:mm:ss.SSS} [%thread] %-5level %logger{36} - %msg%n</pattern>
    </encoder>
  </appender>
  <root level="WARN"> <!-- set loglevel here-->
    <appender-ref ref="STDOUT" />
  </root>
</configuration>
```