# activate tinkerpop plugins for Titan

Tags: titan, gremlin

I'm new in Graph databases. When I am using Titan,
I run Gremlin and these 3 lines **do not** appear :

> plugin activated: tinkerpop.server
>
> plugin activated: tinkerpop.utilities
>
> plugin activated: tinkerpop.tinkergraph

and when I'm trying to run any line of code this exception appears:

> no such property : tinkergraph for class :groovysh_evaluate

How can I fix this problem?
Best regards

Comment: Can you describe your environment a bit more? What OS, Java version? Are you using [titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/downloads/titan/titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip)?

Comment: OS : Windows 
Java 8
and     titan-1.0.0-hadoop1.zip

Comment: I've [opened an issue](https://github.com/thinkaurelius/titan/issues/1242) against Titan. In the meantime, you can try using the gremlin.bat and gremlin-server.bat from [here](https://github.com/pluradj/titan/tree/titan11-windows-bat/titan-dist/src/assembly/static/bin) and let me know if those resolve your problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unfortunately, Titan 1.0.0 doesn't work out of the box for Windows. But don't worry, you need to make a small modification to `gremlin.bat` file.

Have a look at this [SO answer.](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33719844/1019952)

Answer (score 0):

The plugins that are loaded when you run Gremlin are set via the file: 
`etc/plugins.txt`

My guess is that there are two different versions of the file on your environment, one for Titan and the other without.